# Unable to change the boot order for grub

Tags: linux, grub2, grub

I have arch and windows in my system. During boot time it is booting to default with Arch. I want to change it to windows.
Entries in grub are like this

1. Arch
2. Arch with multiple option
3. windows

I have tried to change the GRUB_DEFAULT=2 in /etc/default/grub as shown at multiple place as answer for this. It is still booting with default Arch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you set `GRUB_DEFAULT=2`, make sure to run

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

If you get the error

```
bash: update-grub: command not found
```

Then you need to install `update-grub`.

```
$ sudo pacman -S git base-devel
$ git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/update-grub.git
$ yay -S update-grub
$ sudo update-grub
```

Comment: it says no command found on running this command

Comment: See the edits for instructions on how to install `update-grub`

Comment: `update-grub` is just a stub for the command `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` which you should be able to run directly.

Comment: Yes, that is true